# Reading web pages / unicode

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

I have this function in Delphi 2009 /2010

It returns garbage, now if I change the char,pchar types to Ansichar,Pansichar it returns the text but all foreign unicode text is garbage. it drive me banana 
I have been trying all kind of stuff for 2 days now 
I thought I understoff this unicode crap but I guess I do not
Help please
thanks 
Philippe Watel

```
function GetInetFileAsString(const fileURL: string): string;
const
  C_BufferSize = 1024;
var
  sAppName: string;
  hSession,
    hURL: HInternet;

  Buffer: array[0..C_BufferSize] of Char;
  BufferLen: DWORD;

  strPageContent: string;
  strTemp: string;

begin
  Result := '';
  sAppName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);
  hSession := InternetOpen(PChar(sAppName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil,
    nil, 0);
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenURL(hSession, PChar(fileURL), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    try
      strPageContent := '';
      repeat
        InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen);
        SetString(strTemp, PChar(@buffer), BufferLen div SizeOf(Char));
        strPageContent := strPageContent + strTemp;
      until BufferLen = 0;
      Result := strPageContent;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL)
    end
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession)
  end
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Delphi 2009, `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString`, which holds UTF-16 data.  An HTML page, on the other hand, is typically encoded using a multi-byte Ansi encoding instead (usually UTF-8 nowadays, but not always).  Your current code will only work if the HTML is encoded as UTF-16, which is very rare.  You should not be reading the raw HTML bytes into a `UnicodeString` directly.  You need to first download the entire data into a `TBytes`, `RawByteString`, `TMemoryStream`, or other suitable byte container of your choosing, and then perform an Ansi->Unicode conversion afterwards, based on the charset that is specified in the HTTP "Content-Type" response header.  You can use the `Accept-charset` request header to tell the server which charset you prefer the data be sent as, and if the server is not able to use that charset then it should send a `406 Not Acceptable` response (though it MIGHT still send a successful response in an unacceptable charset if it chooses to ignore your request header, so you should account for that).

Try something like this:

```
function GetInetFileAsString(const fileURL: string): string;
const
  C_BufferSize = 1024;
var
  sAppName: string;
  hSession, hURL: HInternet;
  Buffer: array of Byte;
  BufferLen: DWORD;
  strHeader: String;
  strPageContent: TStringStream;
begin
  Result := '';
  SetLength(Buffer, C_BufferSize);
  sAppName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);
  hSession := InternetOpen(PChar(sAppName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    strHeader := 'Accept-Charset: utf-8'#13#10;
    hURL := InternetOpenURL(hSession, PChar(fileURL), PChar(strHeader), Length(strHeader), 0, 0);
    try
      strPageContent := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
        repeat
          if not InternetReadFile(hURL, PByte(Buffer), Length(Buffer), BufferLen) then
            Exit;
          if BufferLen = 0 then
            Break;
          strPageContent.WriteBuffer(PByte(Buffer)^, BufferLen);
        until False;
        Result := strPageContent.DataString;
        // or, use HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_TYPE) to get
        // the Content-Type header, parse out its "charset" attribute,
        // and convert strPageContent.Memory to UTF-16 accordingly...
      finally
        strPageContent.Free;
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I used that code successfully, but I change the buffer to a dynamic array declared buffer: TArray<byte>; and then SetLength(buffer, C_BufferSize). Plus I added a var integer parameter set to zero before the loop and incremented with bufferLen after each call to InternetReadFile. The lets me know the size of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to add the correct AcceptEncoding/CharSet header to the request:

e.g:

Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7